# the cuda local variable makes me confused

Tags: cuda

firstly i think local variable in kernel is only belong to its thread only, but below results make me confused. Could you tell me why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
__global__ void bcast(int arg) {
    int laneId = threadIdx.x & 0x1f;
    int value; // the default value of int type should be 0
    if (laneId == 0) // only thread 0 set value as arg
        value = arg;
    
    printf("thread id %d: %d\n", threadIdx.x, value);

}

int main() {
    bcast<<< 1, 32 >>>(1234);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    return 0;
}
```

I think only thread 0 changed the "value", so the print should be as below:

```
thread id 0: 1234
thread id 1: 0
...
thread id 31: 0
```

however all the "value" of 32 threads are 1234.

then I init “value” with 0 during declaration as below. I get the result I wanted, only thread 0's "value" is 1234, all the others are 0.

```
#include <stdio.h>
    __global__ void bcast(int arg) {
        int laneId = threadIdx.x & 0x1f;
        int value = 0; // init with 0
        if (laneId == 0) // only thread 0 set value as arg
            value = arg;
        
        printf("thread id %d: %d\n", threadIdx.x, value);
   
    }
    
    int main() {
        bcast<<< 1, 32 >>>(1234);
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    
        return 0;
    }
```

my questions are

1. why thread 0 set "value" as "arg",all "value" become "arg" in the
   first code?
2. why thread 0 only set its own "value" after init "value"
   with 0 in the second code?

Comment: "the default value of int type should be 0" -- that's no true

Comment: Some links: Value Initialization https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization which often results in zero initialization https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization ; Default Initialization https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization ; Direct Initialization https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization

Answer (score 4):

> why thread 0 set "value" as "arg",all "value" become "arg" in the first code?

Because there is an **undefined behaviour** in your code. Indeed, `value` is not initialized to 0 as pointed out by @talonmies. It is left uninitialized. Thus, the compiler is free to assume `value` can contain anything including `arg`. In fact, it does so to optimize out the code and remove the condition. You can see on [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/3qEq7Tovz) that your kernel code is equivalent to this one:

```
__global__ void bcast(int arg) {
    int value = arg;
    printf("thread id %d: %d\n", threadIdx.x, value);
}
```

You can fix this by initializing `value` to 0. This is what the second code does.

> why thread 0 only set its own "value" after init "value" with 0 in the second code?

Your code execute a kernel with 1 block and 32 threads. `threadIdx.x` is the thread ID. `threadIdx.x & 0x1f` is equal to 0 only when `threadIdx.x % 32` is zero. Because there is only 32 threads, only the first (`threadIdx.x == 0`) executes the conditional and set the value (while for other threads `value` is still untouched and so set to 0).

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is my misunderstanding about default vaule. So even the buildin type there has no default initialized value in cuda? Besides, godbolt is so cool.

Comment: Yeah Godbolt is a great tool. For Cuda native types, it behaves like C++: the same issue would be present in a C++ code (though compiler optimizations may be less aggressive regarding the use-case).